# How to change y-axis increments in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently have a graph in Matplotlib with the y-axis incrementing by .5 up to 2.0. How would I change it so it increments by .3? Such that it goes 0, .3, .6, .9, 1.2....?

Comment: Matplotlib sets ticks based on the chosen locator. What you describe is a [MultipleLocator](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=tick%20locators#tick-locating) (or maybe a FixedLocator) for the major ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know exactly the increments you are looking for, you can use [`matplotlib.pyplot.yticks(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html) or [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks(...)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html) depending on how you are interacting with `matplotlib`. Simply pass the list of ticks you want to use.